# Pass row number as variable and reference other sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, row, transpose

I have a row of data on one sheet (`Harvest targets`) that I want to transpose to another sheet (`Field worksheet`) into an array.

On the second sheet (`Field worksheet`), I have a drop down list (`A31`) to choose the crop, and I have a cell next to it (`I31`) that outputs the row number the crop is on in the first sheet (`Harvest targets`). I am trying to use the following formula, but it's not working (I get an error):

```
=TRANSPOSE('Harvest targets'!(INDIRECT("X" & I31):INDIRECT("AU" & I31)))
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to use `INDIRECT` to look up the correct row in the other sheet, which is set by `I31`, in a predetermined range of columns (`X:AU`).

Answer (score 1):

INDIRECT is a little difficult to work with, especially in such constructions, as well as being volatile. INDEX is more appropriate here:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX('Harvest targets'!X:X,I31):INDEX('Harvest targets'!AU:AU,I31))
```

Regards